# Access instance/service from Vuex that was provided to Vue (Vue.js 3)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

### Background

Consider the following:

```
// app.js
import API from 'utils/API';

const api = new API(config.app.urls.api, endpoints, token);

app.provide('$api', api);
```

Based on everything I have read in the past 24 hours, the above is the advised method of providing a 'service' to Vue.js 3.

However, the issue with the above is that I now cannot access the API instance as the [`inject`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#provide-inject) method cannot be used outside of a Vue component.

As such, when I want to import the API instance into my Vuex modules, I can't...

### Question

Is there an 'advised' way of accessing a provided service outside of a Vue component? Or is one of my proposed solutions below how it *should* be done?

### Possible Solutions

**Proposed Solution 1**

Instead of providing the service to Vue, we can just add it to the global properties like so:

```
// app.js
app.config.globalProperties.$api = api;
```

and then we can access it like so in the store:

```
// some-vuex-module.js
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';

const api = getCurrentInstance().appContext.config.globalProperties.$api;
```

I am using the above for certain things in my app but for the API service it just seems wrong to do it this way.

**Proposed Solution 2**

Another solution I thought of was to just make the API instance available to the window like so:

```
// app.js
import API from 'utils/API';

const api = window.api = new API(config.app.urls.api, endpoints, token);

app.provide('$api', api);
```

The above seems like an anti-pattern though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preferable method in modular environment (which Vue 3 setup is commonly is) is to just import `api` in places where it's used, regardless of whether it's used inside or outside the component.

The solution with Vue global property originated at the time when Vue applications weren't necessarily modular so they relied on Vue instance as global application scope. Currently it's suitable only for properties that are primarily used in a template and require boilerplate code to import and expose them. The example is `$t` in `vue-i18n`.

The solution with `provide`/`inject` is usable for cases that need dependency injection. A common case is a library that require dependencies to be loosely coupled. Another one is that a dependency depends on component hierarchy and may vary between components.

The solution with `window` should be avoided, unless application is divided into separate scripts that cannot interact through common JS modules. Even then the problem is that a script that defines global variable should be loaded before those that use it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I absolutely agree about the `window` solution. The issue with importing is that the instance is already instantiated with specific options and I can't import that into the Vuex module... Or can I?

Comment: Can you clarify? You need to have `export const api = new API(...)` in some module, then you can import it where you use it. This should be done in a separate module and not entry point (e.g. main.js) to avoid circular deps

Comment: Yes, I was just thinking that - I can just create a singleton/module and import that, I was just hesitant as I wanted to keep all the logic for creating any providers in one place i.e. app.js.

Comment: A trouble-free way here is to keep entry point lean and not define services there. You could definitely do it the way you tried and use provide/inject, but only if services are exclusively used inside components - which is not the case most times, notably for Vuex.

Comment: Thank you again for the above! Just got a quickie for you... I am about to slightly restructure my project to reflect what you have mentioned i.e. keep the app.js lean and just use it to import the dependencies and create the app instance. My thinking, at the moment, is to create a folder called 'providers' and populate this with service providers for each dependancy - much like Laravel/Lumen. However, is there a more common name for this in JS?

Comment: Vue leaves it to users. `services` dir is a common place for this in project structure. I personally stick to the semantics from Angular where dep/service provider is a class or factory function, and a a dep/service itself is an instance of a provider, often a singleton.