# Use Vue3 inject inside a Typescript class

Tags: typescript, vue.js, inject

I'm creati an error reporting service, and trying to provide it for the entire app.

```js
import ErrorReporter from "@/services/error_reporter/error-reporter.service";

const app = createApp(App);

app.provide('errorReporter', new ErrorReporter());
```

and the importing it in a Ts class like so

```js
import {inject} from "vue";

export default class OAuthFedIdService {

    errorReporter: ErrorReporter = inject("errorReporter") as ErrorReporter;
```

but i get this warning inside the console

```
inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components.
```

is there a way to use the provide/inject functionality of Vue outside of components without getting warnings?

Comment: You're misusing provide/inject. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70607332/access-instance-service-from-vuex-that-was-provided-to-vue-vue-js-3/70607789#70607789

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to use the provide/inject outside of components

Just create and export singleton instance of your service. Use `inject` in components and use direct import anywhere else...